# Danted proxy working with curl but not with anything else

Tags: ubuntu, oracle

I been trying to setup Dante proxy socks5 on oracle cloud ubuntu instance

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS Release:    
20.04 Codename:       focal
```

My danted config:

```
logoutput: /var/log/danted.log

internal: ens3 port = 9050

external: ens3

socksmethod: none

clientmethod: none

user.privileged: root

user.unprivileged: nobody

user.libwrap: nobody

client pass {
        from: 0.0.0.0/0 to: 0.0.0.0/0
        log: connect disconnect error
}

socks pass {
        from: 0.0.0.0/0 to: 0.0.0.0/0
        log: connect disconnect error
}
```

I tried to connect to the proxy using firefox and still doesn't work, though it worked with curl.

> sudo curl -x socks5://<>:9050 ifconfig.co

I dont know where is the messed up part and why is it working with curl but not with browsers.